# Firestore - Invalid query because of uncomitted server timestamp

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've noticed some Android app crash reports that indicate when the user writes a new comment the app will crash when trying to fetch new comments.

**Error**:

> Invalid query. You are trying to start or end a query using a document for which the field 'timestamp' is an uncommitted server timestamp. (Since the value of this field is unknown, you cannot start/end a query with it.)

I've noticed that the problem is caused by **FieldValue.serverTimestamp()** as it writes and updates the field asynchronously.

User a adds a new comment that contains a field:
**("timestamp", FieldValue.serverTimestamp());**

After adding a new comment a RecyclerView triggers a function to load more comments:

```
// Get the last visible document
documentSnapshotCommentsLastVisible = queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments()
        .get(queryDocumentSnapshots.size() - 1);

if (documentSnapshotCommentsLastVisible != null) {
    Query queryNext = documentSnapshot.getReference()
        .collection("comments")
        .orderBy("likes", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
        .orderBy("timestamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
        .startAfter(documentSnapshotCommentsLastVisible)
        .limit(4);
        
    queryNext.get(); // Success listener ...
}
```

I also use Firestore rules that check for timestamp:

```
allow write: if (request.resource.data.timestamp is timestamp && request.resource.data.timestamp == request.time)
```

What would be the best way to avoid crashes like this? Try/catch?

Comment: Have you already checked this [github issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/736)?